# Check SharePoint group exist or not using MS flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, ms-flow, power-automate

I want to check the SharePoint group exist or not using MS flow.

If it exists then do not to create group else create a new SharePoint group using ms flow.

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOTB action in Microsoft flow/ Power Automate to check if the SharePoint Group is present or not.

So, you need to use **Send an HTTP Request to SharePoint** action with below URL to check if SharePoint Group is exists or not.

```
/_api/web/sitegroups?$select=Title&$filter=Title eq 'Site Owners'
```

[image]

[image]

**Expression in "Set Variable" action**:

`body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')['d']['results']`

**Expression in "Condition"**:

`length(variables('ArrGroupResults'))`

If the result of condition is **If yes** that means the group does not exist in SharePoint. So, you can create your group in this **If yes** block.

To create a SharePoint Group and assign permissions check below article by [Siddharth Vaghasia](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/38824/siddharth-vaghasia):

[SharePoint Group Operations In Microsoft Flow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-group-operations-in-microsoft-flow/).

Comment: Have you tried this solution? Is it working for you?